# Find a sum of all the spent time in a day

Tags: tableau-api

I have a table with information about the time that has been spent by every employee.
I want to find a sum of all the spent time in a day by every employee. I want to get the summary table:

Example:

```
Date ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍User ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍Period

20.07.2016   USER1    00:10:24
20.07.2016   USER2    00:26:05
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: It seems your period field is saved a dimension(a string). Right click on it and convert it to a measure and try again.

Answer (score 0):

'Period' is not of a number format. It seems to be of either String or Datetime. Converting it before carrying out a summation would make it work. If you continue using Datetime, here is a [solution](https://community.tableau.com/message/224840) to get a summation of individual time fields.

Comment: @Zuk21 Was this solution helpful?